# Cross-platform (desktop and mobile) 3D engine

Tags: mobile, 3d, webgl, game-development, 3d-engine

I'm planning on creating a "simple" 3D game/app based on the heightmap demo at http://www.babylonjs.com. The game would really be no more than rotating the camera around an area with some assets, more of a tech demo.

However, that engine utilizes WebGL, which isn't supported on most mobile devices.

I'm looking for a 3D engine that could be used to create a similar app on desktops and mobile devices.

Would [Ludei](http://ludei.com/) be suitable for this task?

Comment: I thought Ludei supported WebGL? http://3d.ludei.com/

Comment: @gman Hence why I mentioned it. But I see your confusion, I originally was referring to web apps, not native or hybrid apps.

Comment: I don't understand your question then. First you say babylonjs uses WebGL and that isn't supported on most mobile devices. Then you suggest Ludei. Ludei's site says "supports WebGL on most devices". Which contradicts your assumption. Theoretically you should be able to use babylonjs in Ludei. All ludei does is take a webpage and turn it into an app. Therefore it should be able to take babylonjs pages and turn them into apps.

Comment: @gman I continued to add to my question as I researched further, so as a whole it is kind of contradictory. I was originally trying to figure out an alternative to WebGL, but after looking into it further I found that platforms like Ludei are able to package an HTML5 app into a hybrid app, thereby encasing WebGL functionality. My assumption of WebGL not being supported on mobile devices was referring to mobile browsers. Regardless, Ludei should serve my purposes fine, so it's all good.

Comment: Google Angle was supposed to enable what the OP has requested, but existence proof of this is limited to what you can build inside of the Angle source tree.  I am curious to see if anyone has managed to integrate precompiled binaries from Angle for use in iOS/Android, or the WebGL (in Chrome) use case.

Answer (score 0):

Ludei looks interesting, I think I'll take a look into that myself.

For cross-platform development, take a look at [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/). This is a framework that lets you write all your code in Java and then compile for various platforms (Windows/Mac desktop, Android, iOS.) I believe it can also compile to HTML5/JS/WebGL.

Answer (score 0):

libGDX is great, unfortunately it lack of enough tutorials and material on 3D.